# NodeJS app crashes when requests MSSQL DB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sql-server, docker, nestjs

Good day everyone!

I have an old app from dev that now isn't working in our company. I need to start this app but don't have enough experience in NodeJS (I don't have it at all, TBH).

The problem is: I can build a docker image, start it, and use the app, but when I make something that requires to make a request to MQSQL server, the app crashes.
But there are no issues with requests to Postgres DB.

This is my docker build output

```
    docker build -t fixver .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.427MB
Step 1/21 : FROM node:16-alpine as base
 ---> c4ee3c9d7bc1
Step 2/21 : ARG NODE_ENV=production
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ba79cfac2e2c
Step 3/21 : ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}     NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=8192"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1a344f8791d8
Step 4/21 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1c591a772bcd
Step 5/21 : FROM base as clientBuilder
 ---> 1c591a772bcd
Step 6/21 : COPY ./client/package.json ./client/yarn.lock ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7382b944fcc0
Step 7/21 : RUN yarn install --production=false --frozen-lockfile
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 431700be035b
Step 8/21 : COPY ./client .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87790e7c061a
Step 9/21 : RUN yarn build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9ba70dd8301c
Step 10/21 : FROM base as serverBuilder
 ---> 1c591a772bcd
Step 11/21 : COPY ./server/package.json ./server/yarn.lock ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bf5dc70ee2eb
Step 12/21 : RUN yarn install --production=false --frozen-lockfile
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c26b02f2af5c
Step 13/21 : COPY ./server .
 ---> 16fdc772d650
Step 14/21 : RUN yarn build
 ---> Running in 676753d20a77
yarn run v1.22.19
$ node_modules/.bin/rimraf dist
$ node_modules/.bin/nest build
Done in 5.75s.
Removing intermediate container 676753d20a77
 ---> 66a53b6af7cd
Step 15/21 : FROM base as production
 ---> 1c591a772bcd
Step 16/21 : COPY ./server/package.json ./server/.env ./
 ---> dbbbe7295cfd
Step 17/21 : RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile
 ---> Running in f3b965d1ec0d
yarn install v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "uuid@8.3.2" is incompatible with requested version "uuid@^3.1.0"
warning jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > ts-loader@9.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 39.04s.
Removing intermediate container f3b965d1ec0d
 ---> 8d804071a8d2
Step 18/21 : COPY --from=serverBuilder /usr/src/app/dist ./
 ---> f760fda4b1a1
Step 19/21 : COPY --from=clientBuilder /usr/src/app/build ./public
 ---> 4f697bab8bc6
Step 20/21 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 95fae0df9266
Removing intermediate container 95fae0df9266
 ---> 4bebff7957bc
Step 21/21 : CMD ["node", "./main"]
 ---> Running in 19b4df36b37e
Removing intermediate container 19b4df36b37e
 ---> 362fbadf0b4a
Successfully built 362fbadf0b4a
Successfully tagged fixver:latest
```

Starting the app

```
docker run -p 7007:80 fixver
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +60ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ServeStaticModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +8ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] PagesModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ScriptsModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] ScriptsController {/api/scripts}: +8ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/scripts, GET} route +4ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/scripts/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/scripts/:id/check, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/scripts/:id/apply, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] PagesController {/api/pages}: +1ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/pages/:id, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +5ms
[Nest] 1  - 12/01/2022, 1:49:54 PM     LOG Server started! Port: 80
```

And error right after making request to MSSQL

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: No event 'featureExtAck' in state 'SentLogin7WithNTLMLogin'
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1663:26)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1224:12)
    at Parser.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/token-stream-parser.js:27:14)
    at Readable.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at next (node:internal/streams/from:98:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Readable instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

I really don't know what to do with it, how to debug it and find the problem.
Any help and advise is appreciated.

Comment: you could wrap the method which makes the request in a `try/catch` and debug from this point

Comment: The `featureExtAck` message has been part of TDS (Tabular Data Stream) since version 7.4 (SQL Server 2012), so something is either very old or very new here. What version of SQL Server are you connecting to (what does `SELECT @@VERSION` report when connected via SSMS) and what version of the `tedious` Node package are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing this code in Dockerfile

```
-COPY ./server/package.json ./server/.env ./
-RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile
+COPY ./server/package.json ./server/yarn.lock ./server/.env ./
+RUN yarn install --production=true --frozen-lockfile
```